# Model helper in rails and render in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I want to write some method in model helper and render in my view. My Product model has price column. In the view I want to be able to write @product.tier_one_quantity_one for example. How to write the helper and how to render?

Can I assign multiple variables in a single method?

```
module ProductsHelper
  def price_variation(product)
    @tier_one_quantity_one = @product.price * 1.2
    @tier_one_quantity_wo = @product.price * 1.4
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Helpers take a more functional approach:

```
module ProductsHelper
  def tiered_price(product, tier, quantity)
    price = case tier
      when 1 then product.price * 1.2
      when 2 then product.price * 1.4
      else product.price * 1.6
    end
    price * product.quantity
  end
end

# view
<%= number_to_currency( tiered_price(@product, 1, 2) ) %>
```

But it seems to me that this would be better in the model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tiered_price(tier, quantity)
    price = case tier
      when 1 then price * 1.2
      when 2 then price * 1.4
      else price * 1.6
    end
    price * quantity
  end
 end

 # view
 <%= number_to_currency(@product.tiered_price(1, 2)) %>
```

If you really want to be able to write @product.tier_one_quanity_two like find_by_name, you'll need to hook into method_missing, which has some complexity and speed overhead, but would go something like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    match = method.to_s.match(/tier_(.*)_quantity_(.*)/)
    if match && match[0] && match[1]
      unit_price = case match[0]
        when 'one' then price * 1.2
        when 'two' then price * 1.4
        else price * 1.6
      end
      quantity = case match[1]
        when 'one' then 1
        when 'two' then 2
        #.. and so on
      end 
      unit_price * quantity
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to render multiple price variations for every single product, not getting the right price from various scenarios. These variations are calculated from product.price column

Comment: Actually what I need to do is `tier_three_quantity_one = product.price`. `tier_three_quantity_two = tier_three_quantity_one * (1- VOLUME) where VOLUME = 0.02` Same goes with tier 4 `Tier_four_quantity_one = product.price * (1 + PERCENTAGE) where PERCENTAGE = 0.2`